# How does a buck converter increase current?

Tags: power, dc-dc-converter, buck

I am confused regarding this.  In a buck converter, Pin=Pout.  If I reduce the voltage then the current has to increase. If my resister load is fixed at, say, 5 ohms and resistors follow Ohm's law, then  according to that current should decrease if the voltage is reduced.

Can you tell me where I am wrong?

Comment: Here is a good explanation, https://www.quora.com/How-exactly-does-a-DC-to-DC-buck-converter-reduce-voltage-and-increase-current

Comment: Not everything follows Ohm's law and the buck converter is a good example of explicitly not following it.

Answer (score 2):

If we consider all non-load components to have no losses, then you can generally say that

PowerIn = PowerOut.

But I assume that the intended question is something more like:

How does a buck converter produce more current at the output than is provided at the (higher voltage) input?

In short, the buck converter does not actually manufacture charges flowing as current at the output.  It is more like it "RECYCLES" the charges during the 'off' portion of the PWM signal because the inductor forces current to continue to flow around the inductor-loadResistor-diode loop as its magnetic field collapses.

[image: Switch Closed]The first simple schematic is the 'on' portion.  Current flows in the loop from the input supply V1, through the closed switch, through the inductor, through a load resistor, and back to the input supply.  As the current increases in the loop, a magnetic field is created in the inductor and increases in strength.  During this time, current flowing from the input supply is the same current flowing through the load resistor R1.

[image: Switch Open]This second simple schematic depicts the 'off' portion of the cycle.  The switch is open so there is NO current (therefore no power) flowing from the input supply V1.  Instead, the now-collapsing magnetic field in the inductor L1 creates a voltage difference across it that causes current to continue to flow through the load resistor, the diode, and back to the inductor.  This seems like 'free' power now being consumed by the load, but it is actually being provided at this point by the inductor, which stored energy while the input power supply was providing current.  The lower the voltage you need across the load, the longer those same charges will circulate in this second smaller loop.

The input power supply is sourcing current at voltage for some fraction of the time (while the switch is closed).  The buck converting power supply is providing current at a lower voltage for, essentially, 100% of the time.

In a lossless system, you would get a (VoltageIn/VoltageOut) ratio in the current seen flowing across the load when compared to the current flowing out of the input power supply.  The time-averaged electrical power out of the system (VoltageOut * CurrentOut) would equal the time-averaged electrical power put into it (VoltageIn * CurrentIn).

(images were derived from schematics created with Circuit Lab)

Answer (score 1):

The **available** power is based on Pin = Pout,

BUT, if you reduce the voltage into a fixed value resistor, then the current reduces appropriately as per Ohm's law.

Your confusion is about the power staying constant, it is available if you change the resistor...

Comment: True. The OP may have the same misconception that many people have in ideal transformers, namely that the power is constant. This is false. The equation is P_out = P_in. This does not imply that P_out or P_in = constant; it implies that P_out and P_in are always equal to each other. E.g. if the input/primary voltage is fixed, then changing the load at the output/secondary side from R = R_1 to R = R_2 > R_1 will decrease P_in and P_out (with both being the same), meaning they aren't constant (when compared when R = R_1).

Answer (score 1):

You say that you are reducing the voltage, so current through the 5Ω should decrease, but you are forgetting that *you are not reducing the voltage across the 5Ω load*, you are reducing it at the input to the buck converter. The load voltage does not change.

The whole point of the converter is to produce a fixed ouput voltage regardless of voltage changes at its input, so it's essential to specify exactly where those changes are occuring. In this case it's certainly not across the load.

Sure, if you modified your converter to output a different voltage, *then* the current through the resistive load would change.

I agree that power in = power out (for a hypothetical 100% efficient converter). Since the output voltage is constant, and the output current must be too (given a constant 5Ω load), then power out (\$ P_{OUT} = I_{OUT} \times V_{OUT}\$) is also constant.

Clearly, then, if the *input voltage* changes, then for input power to remain the same as this constant output power, it must be *input current* that is changing to compensate (\$ P_{IN} = I_{IN} \times V_{IN}\$), and *not* the current in the load.

Answer (score 0):

If you reduce the voltage supplied to a fixed load resistance then the load current must decrease according to Ohm's Law. But if you use a buck converter to decrease voltage the supply current will reduce *more* than the load current.

For example, if you power a 5Ω load from a 10V supply then the current will be 10V/5Ω = 2A. If you then drop the load voltage to 5V using eg. a series resistor or linear regulator, both the load current and the supply current will be 5V/5Ω = 1A. So the supply is delivering 10V*1A = 10W, the load is consuming 5V*1A = 5W, the other 5W is dissipated as heat in the voltage dropping device, and the conversion efficiency is 50%.

However if you use a buck convertor the output power will only be slightly less than the input power. If the buck converter is 90% efficient then 5W at the output equates to 5W/0.9 = 5.56W at the supply. 5.56W/10V = 0.556A, ie. 55.6% of the 1A output current to the load. So the output current of the buck converter has increased *compared to the input current*, and the supply current has reduced *more* than the load current.